# vue: using a v-for for semi-dynamic object

Tags: vue.js

I have a list of ID's from the vuex store.

`idList = [23,54,66]`

I want to use a `v-for` to iterate that list and then create a new data model that looks like this below but unsure how to set up my v-model code:

```
newData = {
     [ 
       {
        id: 23,
        url: // based off v-text-field,
        key: //based off v-text-field
       },
       {
        id: 54,
        url: // based off v-text-field,
        key: //based off v-text-field
       },
       {
        id: 66,
        url: // based off v-text-field,
        key: //based off v-text-field
       },
     ]
    }
```

my code so far:

```
<v-checkbox
    class="stream-targets"
    v-for="(target,index) in idList"
    v-model="locationTarget"
    :value="target"
>
    <template v-slot:label>
       <span class="check-text" v-model='???'>{{ target}} [{{ target}}]</span>
       <v-text-field placeholder="URL" v-model='??'></v-text-field>
       <v-text-field placeholder="Key" v-model='??'></v-text-field>

    </template>
</v-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

U nead something like this:

in vuex:

```
state: {
       idList: [23,54,66]
   },
```

in component and in created() method:

```
 var idList = this.$store.state.idList;
    idList.forEach(el => {
      this.newData.push({
        id: el,
        url: '',
        key: ''
      });
  });
```

and in component:

```
<v-checkbox
    class="stream-targets"
    v-for="(target,index) in newData"
    :key="index"
    v-model="locationTarget"
    :value="target"
>
    <template v-slot:label>
       <!-- <span class="check-text" >{{target.id}}</span> -->
       <v-text-field placeholder="URL" v-model='target.url'></v-text-field>
       <v-text-field placeholder="Key" v-model='target.key'></v-text-field>
    </template>
    
</v-checkbox>
```